# the event listener call the wrong function

Tags: actionscript, audio

i need help in action script 3.0 code. i develop a shooting game. the problem is that i have a button `sound_btn` where the user need to click to play sound. That button has function `SoundButton` that will play sound of the alphabet character (which is 5 different buttons on the stage"letter1,2,3...etc") that user need to shoot. if the user shoot the right answer image will show up and he/she will score. When the user shoot the button if its right it will go the right `_answer`  function ,if it’s wrong it will go to wrong `_answer` function. But unfortunately the shooting target whether it right or wrong it goes to the right_answer function I can’t find the mistake.i put trace to know the value of i and it seems that i generate twic the same value which i think the function run twice.i realy don't know the answer pleas help me.

```
    sound_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, SoundButton);
    function SoundButton(evt:MouseEvent): void
    { //to hide the right marks
    right.visible=false;
 right2.visible=false;
 right3.visible=false;
 right4.visible=false;
 right5.visible=false;
 trace(i);

     if (i==0)
     { 

     myChannel = mysound.play();

    letter1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Right_Answer);
letter2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);


}

else if (i==1) 
     {

     myChannel1 = mysound1.play();

     letter1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Right_Answer);
letter4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);

}

else if (i==2)
{

    myChannel2 = mysound2.play();

    letter1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Right_Answer);
letter5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);

}

else if (i==3)
{

    myChannel3 = mysound3.play();

    letter1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Right_Answer);

}

else if(i==4)
{

    myChannel4 = mysound4.play();

    letter1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Right_Answer);
letter3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);


} 
    }
    function Wrong_Answer(event:MouseEvent)
    {
if (i==0){
 right.visible=true;
 i++;
 }
 else if (i==1){
     right2.visible=true;
     i++;
     }
 else if (i==2){
     right5.visible=true;
     i++;
     }
 else if (i==3){
     right3.visible=true;
     i++;
     }
 else if (i==4)
 {
     right4.visible=true;
     i++;

 }

 // move to next frame when the game is finish

     if (i>4)
     {
      nextFrame();
      }

  return i;

  //remove the event 
  letter1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter5.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);



    }
    //show the right answer

    function Right_Answer(event:MouseEvent)
    {

 //for the scoring 
 score=score+1;
 score_show.text=(score).toString();
 i++;

 if (i>4)
     {
      nextFrame();
     }


 letter1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Right_Answer);
 letter2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Right_Answer);
 letter3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Right_Answer);
 letter4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Right_Answer);
 letter5.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Right_Answer);
 return i; 
     }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.
I don't know what is variable *i(button?)* in your sample. But if you try to add handlers for each *i(button?)* you will have two handlers (Right_Answer, Wrong_Answer) on each buttons. In this case Right_Answer handler will fire on every click.

Comment: i use i as counter where i by defualt =0 and the more the user shoot the button in the stage the i will increase.that how i make the button play the second sound after shooting the first character, is there another way to play the second sound file after the first sound file got answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not removing the event listeners properly.  You can't add these events like so

```
letter1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Right_Answer);
letter3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
```

And then remove them like this:

```
letter1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
letter5.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Wrong_Answer);
```

You now have removed all the event listeners except:

```
letter5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Right_Answer);
```

If you move onto the next frame you will have an event listener left over that will trigger the incorrect result on the next frame.  Over time you will build up more and more "incorrect" results and listeners on your letters and buttons.

I suggest you remove exactly the event listeners you added.  So you can avoid duplicate or more listeners on each letter.